docker how can I get a more verbose output for 'RUN run-composer'
I am updating a symfony project and currently my docker build via Github Actions in the google cloud is crashing with the following message:
   26 |     
  27 |     USER nginx
  28 | >>> RUN run-composer
  29 |     RUN composer dump-env prod
  30 |     RUN bin/console cache:clear
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c run-composer" did not complete successfully: exit code: 255
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c run-composer" did not complete successfully: exit code: 255

The matching part of my Docker file looks like this:
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www

USER nginx
RUN run-composer
RUN composer dump-env prod
RUN bin/console cache:clear
RUN bin/console cache:warmup


How can I get a more verbose output?
The errorcode 255 just says " there was an error" Well duh....
RUN run-composer -v doesn't help either.
So how can I get more information abut what is going wrong here? How can I make the output more verbose?

What does run-composer do? Is that a script you wrote on your own?

The answer was there all the time, but you have to see it.
During the build you get hundreds of lines output in the view. Some 100 lines above a fatal error was mentioned including the stack trace. So I now have more information about the problem.
